# AXUIElement available in MonoMac?

Tags: cocoa, monomac

I'd like to be able to use the Cocoa Accessibility API in a MonoMac application, but I can't find any references to it in the MonoMac documentation. Has AXUIElement.h been mapped yet?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything on it either.

Some parts can be implemented with DllImport. For example, I did the following:

```
public const string AccessibilityLibrary = "/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/ApplicationServices";

[DllImport (AccessibilityLibrary)]
extern static bool AXAPIEnabled();
```